# How do I filter out by time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an hstore column in my ActiveRecord `Foo` model named `properties`, which has a key called `check_for_new_plan_at`, which contains the following value `"2015-07-14T14:51:42+00:00"`

How do I search/filter against this. I tried

```
Foo.where("(properties -> 'check_for_new_plan_at')::TIME <= ?", Time.now.utc).first
```

The SQL (rendered in Rails console) returns:

```
SELECT  "foos".* FROM "foos"  WHERE "foos" ((properties -> 'check_for_new_plan_at')::TIME <= '2014-07-17 15:02:42.175381')  ORDER BY "foos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Which returns 0 results. Should I be typecasting to unix timestamp or something and then comparing to `Time.now.utc.to_i` instead?

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: a simple `Foo.where('check_for_new_plan_at <= ?', DateTime.current)` should be sufficient

Comment: @MrYoshiji `check_for_new_plan_at` is not an ordinary column. It is a key in an hstore column. As such, it is stored as a string

Answer (score 0):

Use time in iso8601 format. This will print date in format `2015-07-14T14:51:42Z`. To print '+0000' instead use `localtime` instead of `utc`

```
Time.now.localtime('+00:00').iso8601
```